# Archaic word for snooping or going through someone’s medicine cabinet without permission

Tags: word-request, verbs, archaic-language

My grandmother, born in 1914, used a word that sounds like "*prefinelle*" to describe snooping or going through someone’s medicine cabinet or drawers without permission.
Does anyone know the proper spelling of that word? Is it a real word?

Comment: More details? Where did she grow up?

Comment: Can you use the word in a sentence? Or at least give us some hint what part(s) of speech it is?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't just mishear "to pilfer"?

Comment: Can I confirm that your grandmother is a native speaker of English? Which dialect? English? Scottish? American? something else?  Can you use the word in a sentence? "Pilfer" seems like a stretch, but I can think of nothing closer.

Comment: Which syllable is accented? That might help me.